# sorting by month, week number (integer with string) and year in Python

Tags: python, sorting

In python, i have an array of dates in this format (January, Week 1, 2022).
I would like to sort first by year, then month and then week number.

Just to give a visual representation, below is one example of an array of dates.

```
January, Week 4, 2022 
January, Week 3, 2022
January, Week 2, 2022
December, Week 5, 2022
November, Week 1, 2021
October, Week 5, 2021
October, Week 2, 2021
September, Week 3, 2021
September, Week 1, 2021
August, Week 1, 2021
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html

Comment: I was not able to wrap my mind around due to the index with the week string. Also, i was not sure how to segment my sorting by index positions.  After researching i was still not able to wrap my mind around it but after seeing one of the answers below, i can now see i do not need to "segment" my sorting by indexes.  The datetime class seems to do all the work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions, but if you don't mind to use hack for it, you can use [strptime](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) with proper format:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "January, Week 4, 2022"
fmt = "%B, Week %d, %Y"
dtime = datetime.strptime(s, fmt)
```

Here %B stands for month full name, %Y is a year and (here is a hack) %d is a day. If we prepare list of datetimes we can sort it with their natural order

```
sorted([datetime.strptime(s, fmt) for s in input_list]) # or with reverse=True
```

At the end you can return to str format with **datetime.strftime**

Comment: That was simpler than what i thought it would be!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.. If you use the sort() function. It arranges based on your requirements (ascending, depending etc..)

```
from datetime import datetime
my_dates = ['5-Nov-18', '25-Mar-17', '1-Nov-18', '7-Mar-17']
my_dates.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y"))
print(my_dates)
```